# Facing Difficulty While Setting Screen Orientation Of Activity At Run Time

Tags: android

Hi Friends,
I've an Activity, I want this to run in Portrait mode for **240x320**  and in landscape mode for **320x240**. so in Activity's onCreate() method i'm requesting for screen Orientation

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

           if(is320x240)
              setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE); 
           else
              setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT); 

}
```

my promblem is: When i launch this activity in 320x240 device, by holding the device in portrait mode, activity get existing automatically (activity appears fraction of second). But if i hold device in landscape mode while launching, it works fine.

What is the problem? and how can i launch the activity in landscape mode, even-though user holds the device in portrait mode?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you setting the content view after the above code?

Comment: yes i'm setting content view after the code which i posted

Comment: "Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@4425e6f0"

- This is what my logcat says

Comment: You should maybe set the content view before the code you posted, as done in the Krishna suggestion link. Or maybe edit your code to show us also the setcontentview().

Comment: @Zappescu i've tried that too

Answer (score 0):

On create is call every time When we change orientation of device. Solution is very simple
set below property in Mainfest file of Activity.
**android:configChanges="touchscreen|keyboard|keyboardHidden|navigation|orientation"**